# Extracting information from a text file with python

Tags: python, python-3.4

I've a project that includes writing a program that extracts certain data (numeric) from a text file, that has to be generalized to function with different text files the in the same format.

The file is an analyse of a molecule, the data to extract is the coordinates of every atom inside the molecule, so it has to be generalised in a way that it extracts as much data as there ate atoms in different files.

Here's what i've come up with so far:

```
def Prog1():
f=open( "C:/dimer.out","r" )
m=open("C:/dimer1.out","w")
g=f.readlines()
for k in range(len(g)):
    if "Standard" in g[k]:
        c=k
for n in range(c+5, len(g)):
    m.write(g[n])
    if "------------" in g[n+1]:
        break
```

This basically extracts the lines with the information and writes them in a new text file, in a generalised way according to the file format. ( the lines with the information start always 5 lines after the line which includes 'Standard', and are always followed by a line with a lot of '-----'.
Then;

```
def Prog2():
X=[]
Y=[]
Z=[]
m=open('C:/dimer1.out','r')
n=0
for line in m:
    n+=1
k=n
data = csv.reader(m, delimiter=" ")
for i in range(k):
    M=next(data)
    while '' in M:
        M.remove('')
    X.append(M[3])
    Y.append(M[4])
    Z.append(M[5])
```

this is intended to extract the exact data in those lines and put them in their respective lists. (there are spaces in between the data and the data to extact are numbers with multiple characters. But i'm getting an error 'Stopiteration' on M=next(data). What is the error? or how can i modify it to work?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `StopIteration` happens because there's no more data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these two lines together:

```
m = open('C:/dimer1.out', 'r')

for line in m:
    n += 1

...

data = csv.reader(m, delimiter=' ')
for i in range(k):
    M = next(data)
```

Once you've done `for line in m`, you've exhausted the file object. The file head is now at the end of the file, so when you go to read through it again as a `csv.reader`, you aren't coming up with anything.

At any point between the `for line in m` loop and the `for i in range(k)` loop, do `m.seek(0)`. That will put the file head back at the start of the file, and allow you to read it through again.